# Не работает задать Accept-Language в webbrowser c#

Tags: c#

Пробовал открыть некоторые сайты(facebook, openstreetmap, instagram) в webbrowser с передачей POST запроса. Пробовал различные варианты и языки.

> "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"

Это функция не работает совсем? Пытался передать и POST со всеми параметрами такими как Accept, Cache-Control, User-Agent. Не выходит кто подскажет, кто поможет. Уже 2 день копаюсь не выходит.

```
        string h = "Accept-Language: ru-RU";
        mapWebViewer.Navigate("https://www.instagram.com", "", null, h);
```

Comment: Возможность отдавать контент на разных языках должен поддерживать сам сайт. Вы уверены, что фейсбук её поддерживает? Инстаграмм?

Comment: В пример GoogleCrome эти сайты отображаются на русском, а в проекте c# они отображаются на английском. И я узнавал что передав в Headers в webbrowser.Navigate(,,,**additionalHeaders**) должна передаться локализация.

Answer (score 0):

Различные сайты по-разному определяют язык, на котором необходимо возвращать контент сайта пользователю. Некоторые сайты действительно смотрят на содержимое заголовка "Accept-Language".

Конкретно на примере сайта instagram.com, по умолчанию пользователю выдается страница локализованная в зависимости от местоположения\региона.
Однако выдаваемый язык интерфейса можно переопределив передав с запросом в Cookie с именем "ig_lang" двухбуквенный код локали(ru, en, fr, и т.д.).

WebBrowser из System.Windows.Forms не имеет API позволяющего задавать Cookie перед запросом. Однако используя механизм P/Invoke можно задать Cookie следующим образом:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);

private void Load() {
    var url = "https://www.instagram.com";
    var langCookie = new Cookie("ig_lang", "en", "", "/") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) };
    InternetSetCookie(url, null, langCookie.ToString());
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url, "", null, "");
}
```

Comment: К сожалению даже это не прокатило. Мне собственно нежен именно openstreetmap.org и почему то мне кажется что проблема в другом так как подобные вопрос задавался на их форуме и все таки этот сайт определяет как раз по пост запросу 

**https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/1966/how-to-select-language-for-main-map-page?page=1&focusedAnswerId=1977#1977**

Comment: Тогда вы немного неверно сформулировали вопрос. Как я и писал, выдача данных на определенном языке зависит от конкретного сайта и в общем случае нельзя дать ответ какой способ используется на том или ином сайте. По указанной вами ссылке ответ на вопрос как вывести локализованные названия в результате GET-запроса. Для этого достаточно в URL запроса добавить параметр &accept-language=ru. Ваш вариант с Accepted-Language не работает т.к. вы используете контрол WebBrowser, который не заменяет дефолтное значение Accepted-Language на то, что передается в параметре метода Navigate.

Comment: Также, если в отображении нет необходимости, то для взаимодействия с API рекомендую использовать класс HttpClient и дополнительные инструменты типа Fiddler для отслеживания запросов, которые отправляются с клиента на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб передать параметр напиши 
Переменная-запроса.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "parametrs");
Используй Xnet , он проще в плане запросов нежели дефолт шарпа

Comment: Язык вроде сменился, но появилась новая проблема как вывести его полностью в webbrowser. Я response как текст передал в documentText выводится только текст. Stream передать не вышло.